# Service doesn't start upon server restart

Tags: centos, systemd, reboot

I have the following script in the `/etc/systemd/system/` folder.

```
# Start the ruby on rails app on boot
[Unit]
Description=Start Ruby Online Ordering Application

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
Username=root
PIDFile=/home/deviant/www/tmp/pids/server.pid
WorkingDirectory=/home/deviant/www
ExecStart=/home/deviant/www/run.sh
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

with a permission of `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root`

The *run.sh* script contains

```
#!/bin/sh
service httpd stop
rails s -p 80 -d
```

with a permission of `-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root`

In short, it is supposed to start a Ruby application upon restart of a server, however, it does not appear to be working.

Where can I check to see system error logs?
What would cause it NOT to start upon a server restart?

I tried changing the script to:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
PIDFile=/home/deviant/www/tmp/pids/server.pid
WorkingDirectory=/home/deviant/www
ExecStart=/home/deviant/www/run.sh
TimeoutSec=300
```

And I now get on `systemctl enable....`

> Unknown lvalue 'Username' in section 'Service'
> ...has Restart= setting
> other than no, which isn't allowed for Type=oneshot services.
> Refusing.

I'm not sure what this even means. What does it mean?

Comment: [Please read the answers to this existing question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/442575/258991) You're using `Type=simple`, but it looks like your `run.sh` script will start two processes and then exit. This makes `systemd` think that your service failed, and it will kill off the `httpd` and `rails` child processes, with the assumption that they are just garbage left by the failed service. `Type=simple` is for processes that won't exit until the administrator runs the command to stop the service.

Comment: @telcoM then what should it be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I figure out why my systemctl service didn't start on CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442575/how-do-i-figure-out-why-my-systemctl-service-didnt-start-on-centos-7)

Answer (score 2):

If your Ruby application conflicts with the `httpd` service, I don't see why you should keep that service running just to stop it in your `run.sh`: just run `systemctl disable httpd` once and it won't even be started.

Now you can eliminate your `run.sh` altogether and make your service file with `Type=simple` and `ExecStart=/full/path/to/rails s -p 80`. Note the removal of the `-d` option; this is intentional and works well with `Type=simple`.

For insurance, you can add `Conflicts=httpd.service` to tell `systemd` that your service and `httpd` cannot run at the same time.

So your `/etc/systemd/system/my-ruby-application.service` should look like this:

```
# Start the ruby on rails app on boot
[Unit]
Description=Start Ruby Online Ordering Application
Conflicts=httpd.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Username=root
PIDFile=/home/deviant/www/tmp/pids/server.pid
WorkingDirectory=/home/deviant/www
ExecStart=/some/full/path/rails s -p 80
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To make `systemd` restart your service if it fails for some reason, add a `Restart=` option that is suitable to your requirements (see Table 2 in `man systemd.service`). If you do that, it's recommended to also add a `RestartSec=<sensible restart delay>` to avoid bogging down your server with repeated restart attempts in 0.1s intervals (the default) if your service happens to keep failing after each restart attempt, perhaps because you edited its configuration file and accidentally made a mistake.

Once you've edited your `my-ruby-application.service` file, you should run `systemctl daemon-reload`, then `systemctl disable httpd` and `systemctl stop httpd` if you didn't already do that, and finally `systemctl enable my-ruby-application` and `systemctl start my-ruby-application`.

Comment: Enable/disable imply a daemon-reload, of course.  And the PIDFile is just dross.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reloaded the systemctl daemon ?

```
systemctl daemon-reload  
systemctl enable service_name
```

I know that Centos distros keep boot logs in

```
cat /var/log/boot.log
```